# iOS: Get iPhone passcode to generate symmetric keys for encryption

Tags: ios, encryption

I'm developing an iOS app that is distributed to devices that are all locked with a passcode. Is there a way to get the device passcode (or some form of it) to dynamically generate symmetric keys (for example with PBKDF2) to encrypt/decrypt data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. There is no API to determine if there is a device passcode set or to get the passcode if one is set.

You will need to generate the keys using some other value. One option would be to require the user to enter an app specific passcode.

Comment: Darn, I looked everywhere and couldn't find anything... and that's what I was afraid of. Looks like we'll have to go with the app-specific passcode. Also, (and this is a long shot question...), do you know of any MDMs that may offer this sort of functionality?

Comment: MDM? Don't know that one. Search github.com, I'm pretty sure that are a few passcode entry libraries there.

Comment: Sorry-- MDM = mobile device management, like AirWatch. Many implement their own private security features, which may offer APIs and allow for passcodes or some form of passcodes to be used.